# Is it possible to configure hadoop 2.6.0 running mapreduce v1 framework? (classic)

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I know hadoop 2.6 cluster can be configured to run 'yarn' or 'local', where 'yarn' is mapreduce v2 and 'local' is just local mode. And I learnt from this thread ([What is the difference between classic, local for mapreduce.framework.name in mapred-site.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687029/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-local-for-mapreduce-framework-name-in-ma)) that it can also be configured to run in 'classic' framework, which is mapreduce v1. But I cannot run any job if I simply change 'mapreduce.framework.name' from 'yarn' (or 'local') to 'classic'. So, is it possible to do that? How can I configure it?

My another thought is, I'm using apache hadoop 2.6 distro, does that come with mapreduce v1 framework? If not, I should not be able to configure the cluster to run v1 framework.

**Note, my question is not to run a mapreduce v1 job on hadoop 2.6.0, but configure the cluster in some way, (not 'yarn', not 'local'), running mapreduce v1 framework when got some job.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use hadoop 2.6.0 to configure MR1 or MR2. I have not used Apache, but i use CDH distributon of it where i configured my cluster as MRV1.

Comment: Can you share more details of your configuration? What it your CDH version? How do you configure mapred-site.xml?

Comment: i have used cdh 4.7.1 ... i have this property in mapred-site.xml <property>
 <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
 <value>172.17.1.206:8021</value>
</property>
 you can start jobtracker and task tracker daemons instead of resource manager and node manager daemons. for more info follow this. http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_11_3.html

Comment: One step in this guide is to start the jobtracker, but hadoop 2.6.0 doesn't have a jobtracker. I would look for any other help. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what all daemons you are installing. look here http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_4_4.html