# How do I add link third party libraries when submitting mapreduce jobs through yarn when mapreduce.framework.name is set to local?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I have a jar file yyy.jar that's a third party jar which I want to make available for the mapper of one of the mapreduce tasks that part of a job chain I submit. I'm able to run the map reduce jobs just fine when mapreduce.framework.name is set to yarn but I'm using mapreduce.framework.name=local, I get an exception, Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xxx in java.library.path

The xxx class is actually inside the yyy.jar.

I'm using CDH 5.13

Comment: how do you suggest that MR can work with a "local" framework name? It has to be YARN.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687029/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-local-for-mapreduce-framework-name-in-ma